# Acessar um método que está fora da thread

Tags: java, thread, javafx

Eu tenho um vídeo rodando na minha aplicação e uma Thread rodando um Socket(servidor), todos dentro da mesma classe, mas eu preciso que essa Thread acesse um método que está fora dela.

Pra ser mais exato quero executar o getCurrentTime() para pegar o tempo atual em que o vídeo está rodando e mandar por Socket para outra aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ter acesso ao UI você deve pedir para a API da UI para executar um determinado código na thread de UI, no caso do JavaFX segue o trecho abaixo.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        //Acessar componente de vídeo aqui    
    }
});
```

ou em Java 8

```
 Platform.runLater(() -> {
       //Acessar componente de vídeo aqui    
 }));
```

O detalhe é que esse código sera executado quando a API do JavaFX achar melhor.

Comment: Mesmo se você rodar num ambiente que não seja Java 8, eu realmente recomendo usar a notação lambda. Você consegue fazer a retrocompatibilidade do lambda com as versões anteriores usando o [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)